# Doctrine2 ORM using native query

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have the following command:

```
 $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
        $query = $this->em->createNativeQuery('SELECT userid FROM prospective_shop WHERE LENGTH(bio) = 0 ORDER BY RAND()', $rsm);
        //$query->setMaxResults(10);
        $prospectiveShops = $query->getResult();
```

here it gives me an empty array. I copy pasted that SQL and it worked perfectly fine. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't you forgotten to use:

```
$rsm->addFieldResult(...);
```

to map results of the query to the doctrine object?

EDIT:

try this way:

```
 $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
 $rsm->addEntityResult('my\bundle\Entity\ProsprectiveShop', 's');
 $rsm->addFieldResult('s','userid','userid');
 $query = $this->em->createNativeQuery('SELECT userid FROM prospective_shop s WHERE LENGTH(bio) = 0 ORDER BY RAND()', $rsm);
 $prospectiveShops = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: so in the case above what should I add?

Comment: have you changed the SQL query too? "FROM prospective_shop s "

Comment: edited the response... my bad... just put the correct entity there

Comment: Now this one: Notice: Undefined index: id in /Users/Aditya/Sites/MySite/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 2433